Blender to Unity Rotation Issue
https://youtu.be/ZlZbzr-czxk?si=ml4rcPena76aYeSV
https://youtu.be/qC2lEGxeynU?si=hXFDNC4D8FgXa_pe
I imported a model (block building house) from the repo given in the video description.
I selected mesh named 3, when I run the script selecting 3, it generates 6,9,12 meshes. But initially, it had different rotations (90,0,90) and after running the script the rotation changes to 0,0,0.
The old mesh (where all the objects had rotation 90,0,90) worked well in unity, but new mesh ( rotation(0,0,0) ) produced a weird result.
Script for mesh duplication:https://github.com/3deric/development_tools/blob/master/block_building/meshDuplication.py


This is arguably not directly a Blender related problem, but if you export your model from Blender to Unity, the exporter should have some kind of checkbox to automatically rotate the model since Unity and Blender don't share the same "UP" convention (ie Y axis in Unity versus Z axis in Blender). Or you need to deal with the rotation in Unity on import.

[Solved] Thanks for the information. To export the fbx file, I used "x forward" and "y up" and checked the apply transform checkbox. Now it works as intended in unity.
The rotations in unity for this setting are (0,-90,0).

I tweaked some settings in .fbx export options and imported them in Unity. The default export option for unity is Z forward, Y up, but X forward, Y up worked for me.
Note: Check Apply Transform checkbox if needed.

